# Explorer crashes his flying craft in a strange primitive country

Tags: story-identification

An explorer from an advanced civilization (possibly North America at a far future date) is looking for resources to exploit, in what could be a country left more primitive and isolated as a result of an unspecified cataclysm. His (flying) craft crashes in a strange primitive country; it is probably a plane or helicopter but it's totally unknown to these people.

He is injured and is taken in and cured by a weaver woman, who has been rejected by her culture-bound family. He lives there until his masters - i.e. the people who sent him out to explore - come to rescue him, but he decides to stay in the more peaceful/primitive country.

It is possibly a 1960s or 1970s story and has the same feel as Joan D. Vinge's works.

Comment: This is good. Could you add some details so we know he's from *sci-fi level* civilization (for the time written)?

Comment: Was this a novel or a short story?

Comment: @Jonah What is a "sci-fi level civilization"?

Comment: @user14111 - In other words, we're not talking about someone from a modern society encountering a less industrialized one, i.e. *Robinson Crusoe*. That wouldn't be sci-fi.